# The page isn't redirecting properly error in CAS 3.4.12.1

Tags: tomcat, authentication, single-sign-on, iis-express, cas

I deployed the CAS cas-server-3.4.12.1-release in tomcat. Then I installed the DotNetCasClient 1.0.1 from nuget in visual studio 2012 ultimate. I did following changes in my casClientConfig.

```
 <casClientConfig 
     casServerLoginUrl="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"
     casServerUrlPrefix="https://localhost:8443/cas" 
     serverName="https://localhost:44300/Default.aspx" 
     notAuthorizedUrl="~/NotAuthorized.aspx" 
     cookiesRequiredUrl="~/CookiesRequired.aspx" 
     redirectAfterValidation="true" 
     gateway="false" 
     renew="false" 
     singleSignOut="true" 
     ticketTimeTolerance="5000" 
     ticketValidatorName="Cas20" 
     proxyTicketManager="CacheProxyTicketManager" 
     serviceTicketManager="CacheServiceTicketManager" 
     gatewayStatusCookieName="CasGatewayStatus"
 />
```

I also enabled the SSL in IIS for my web application project and tomcat for cas. I also did following changes in my form authentication module in web.config.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="myForm" loginUrl="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"
         defaultUrl="https://localhost:44300/Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"
         slidingExpiration="true" timeout="30"/>
 </authentication>
  <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

I am banging my head against the wall from this noon, I am able to go to the cas authentication login page but after login I am getting "The Page isn't redirecting properly" error even though the serverName URL changes to

```
https://localhost:44300/Default.aspx?ticket=ST-6-depwZkFolufeJevxaVti-cas
```

When I change casClientConfig from my application URL to google.com its works perfectly fine.

```
  <casClientConfig 
     casServerLoginUrl="https://localhost:8443/cas/login"
     casServerUrlPrefix="https://localhost:8443/cas" 
     serverName="https://www.google.com" 
     notAuthorizedUrl="~/NotAuthorized.aspx" 
     cookiesRequiredUrl="~/CookiesRequired.aspx" 
     redirectAfterValidation="true" 
     gateway="false" 
     renew="false" 
     singleSignOut="true" 
     ticketTimeTolerance="5000" 
     ticketValidatorName="Cas20" 
     proxyTicketManager="CacheProxyTicketManager" 
     serviceTicketManager="CacheServiceTicketManager" 
     gatewayStatusCookieName="CasGatewayStatus"
 />
```

Am I missing any configuration or I am doing it in wrong way. I followed the documentation provided in jasig cas website.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. After I enable SSL in the IIS, I had to import the certificate to cacerts of JVM. And also, I need to add the certificate of tomcat to IIS. I followed

```
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+CASifying+ASP.NET+WebApp+-+ExampleWebsite
```

to solve my problem.